# Efficient way to bind Json to Html?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to find out a better way to bind my json data to my html .

**Json:**

```
$scope.json = { 'one': { 'name': 'level1', 'two': { 'name': 'level2', 'three': { 'name': 'level3' } } } };
```

**Html:**

```
<div ng-controller="myController" >
    <div ng-repeat="data in json">  -- (1)
        <b>{{data.name}}</b>
        <div ng-repeat="data1 in data">
            <b>{{data1.name}}</b>
            <div ng-repeat="data2 in data1 track by $index"><b>{{data2.name}}</b></div>  -- (2)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Pointers :** *//marked in view*

1. There is no array in my json data , so , is there a better way rather using `ng-repeat` (sort of traditional for) . Anything like `with` binding in knockout or templates (i'm not sure How) .
2. I see there are no duplicates in my json but still to compromise the error i have been using `track by $index` at the final inner div(if exclude final div i see no error) .

Answer (score 1):

> 1: There is no array in my json data , so , is there a better way
>   rather using ng-repeat (sort of traditional for) . Anything like with
>   binding in knockout or templates (i'm not sure How) .

There is no way to use JSON object for ng-repeat but you can directly use JSON object using `.` operator for property.

Check below code

```
<div ng-controller="myController" >
    <div>
        <b>{{json.one.name}}</b>
        <b>{{json.one.two.name}}</b>
        <b>{{json.one.two.three.name}}</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

> 2 : I see there are no duplicates in my json but still to compromise
>   the error i have been using track by $index at the final inner div(if
>   exclude final div i see no error).

The reason for error is because you are trying to get index of `JSON object` **which doesn't has index**.